# How can I combine javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Now I have two javascript object，

```
[Object { product_id="4", product_name="test1", book_final_num="9", 更多...}, Object { product_id="6", product_name="test2", book_final_num="9", 更多...}, Object { product_id="8", product_name="test3", book_final_num="7", 更多...}];

[Object { product_id="5", product_name="test", book_final_num="9", 更多...}]
```

I want to combine them to one like this，

```
[Object { product_id="4", product_name="test1", book_final_num="9", 更多...}, Object { product_id="6", product_name="test2", book_final_num="9", 更多...}, Object { product_id="8", product_name="test3", book_final_num="7", 更多...}, Object { product_id="5", product_name="test", book_final_num="9", 更多...}]
```

Comment: Those are not just any 2 objects - they look like Arrays to me. It's important to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for[.extends](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) like this:-

```
var c = $.extend({}, a, b);
```

or may be like this

```
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);
```

Also check out the related [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = array1.concat(array2);
```

BTW, there is something strange in your object notation. It should be

```
[{ product_id:"4", product_name:"test1" ...
```

instead of

```
[Object { product_id="4", product_name="test1", ....
```

Comment: `Object { product_id="4", product_name="test1"` is how the Chrome console prints objects.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does it http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge. All done and dusted.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Didn't come from me, but probably because you gave a jQuery solution when the question wasn't tagged as such. From the JavaScript category description: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NodeJS, check out Merge (https://github.com/yeikos/js.merge)

example:

```
merge({ one: 'hello' }, { two: 'world' })
```

Comment: Here's the NPM page (https://npmjs.org/package/merge)